# Can i access the data on from a windows 7 HD on my windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

My wife has an older PC running windows 7.  I'm building her a new machine using windows 10.  She wants to keep all the files on her old hard drive.  Can I just plug this into the new machine?  Will the windows 7 install cause a problem?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also share files across two PC's.

Comment: Yes - if the user knows how to network, that will certainly work.

Comment: The old PC is going the way of the dodo, it will not be on my network.

Comment: I added the Large USB drive to my answer and that will work.

Comment: Make and model; of new PC?

Comment: just a budget gaming pc.  purchased all the components.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you put the machine in a carrier (USB carrier) and do not try to boot from it - just access files, it will work just fine.

Windows 7 files can be read in Windows 10 without issue.

You can also start the old machine and put the desired files on a large USB Key or USB Drive and then attach the latter to the Windows 10 machine. A 2 TB USB drive is usually decently priced.

Either approach will work. The Carrier approach may be best for a very large amount of data.

Comment: Its almost 1 TB of data.  Not really wanting to move it piece by piece.  I was planning to mount it in the new pc case

Comment: A large (2TB or larger) USB Drive will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whehter these two PCs are located on the same network

1.Transfer Files from PC to PC via the same network, you can use share folder or could drive

2.Transfer Files to new computer via the different network,you can use external device, backup via software or file history.

For more details, please refer to:https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/transfer-files-from-old-pc-to-new-pc-in-windows-10.html